# Firebase find value in database and console log if exist

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database that I am trying to find a value however I am not sure how to find the value of a child with a unique id. what's needed:  If hardware: 'ay12' exist alert(hello)

```
  var ref = fire.database()
  ref.child('Todo').orderByChild('hardware_id').equalTo('ay12').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.key);
        if(data.key){
            alert('exist')
        } else {
            alert('create todo')
        }
    });
});
```

here is the json:
[image]

Comment: The code in itself looks fine to me. Can you edit your question to show the JSON at `/Todo` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).